# Decrypt Saved Password from Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, keystore, encryption

It seems that I have misplaced a password for a Keystore for an Android project.  I still have the keystore, but not the password.  However, the password is saved in Eclipse in the Signing and Keys tab.  I also have the secure_storage file within the org.eclipse.equinox.security directory, and it seems that my stored password is there, encoded.  It makes sense to me that were I to use the stored password-version of the Keystore, that password would need to be decoded at some point, to be passed to the Keystore.  Therefore, I'm wondering what I'd need to do to decode that myself, and retrieve the password.

Any help would be appreciated!

Tim

Comment: I sincerely hope that this is impossible.

Comment: Password hash should be created to be (almost) impossible to decode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much research, I have found how to recover the password from the Secure Storage.  As I surmised, Eclipse must have a way to extract the saved password, otherwise it could never be used to unlock the keystore.  I found this post: [Eclipse password recovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100747/eclipse-password-recovery) which led me into the method to view the saved passwords.  The only bit that took some work was actually executing the code.  I didn't go the eclipse-shell path, but instead created a eclipse plugin project using that code.  Note that that code will not work in a standard Java project.

Of course, the actual Secure Storage is encrypted with the OS authentication, so this would only work for decrypting the password from the machine where it was originally encrypted. The problem was never about decrypting without the proper ciphers, but about using the built-in decrypting methods to get a clean-text password.

Comment: Could you publish your Eclipse plugin?

Answer (score -2):

No, you can not. It uses the operatingsystems cryptation or/and the jvms. Standard is usually some AES-256 bits and is very hard to break.

I don't think you will get any help here.

Comment: Why are you assuming that I *don't* have the password to the secure storage?